# Assembly prints only once

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I have recently started learning assembly and I wanted to print something to the terminal. When I print only one thing, it works, but when I want more, it still prints just the first thing.

My code (assembly x86 on MacOS):

```
global    _main

section   .text

_main:
  mov       rax, 0x02000004
  mov       rdi, 1

  mov r12, message
  mov r11, message.len

  mov       rsi, r12
  mov       rdx, r11
  syscall

  mov r12, message2
  mov r11, message2.len

  mov       rsi, r12
  mov       rdx, r11
  syscall

  mov       rax, 0x02000001
  xor       rdi, rdi
  syscall

section   .data

message db        "Hello, World!"
.len equ $ - message

message2 db "Second hello"
.len equ $ - message2
```

I think I am missing something obvious.

Comment: No idea what's the convention on Darwin for syscalls, but you are not re-setting `rax` before the second syscall. Could it be that its value has not been preserved across the first one and you are making a random syscall as second? Usually `rax` is also where the return value goes, so after the first one `rax` would be `message.len` (in case of success) or some negative error code.

Comment: Thank you very much! I reset `rax` before each sys call and it worked.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Darwin syscalls are quite similar to Linux, but with a high bit set in the call number to indicate what class of system call it is.  Return is in RAX, with CF indicating whether it's a return value or an errno code.  (Unlike Linux with purely in-band signalling of -errno).  MacOS does have some equivalent to `strace`, but I forget what they call it.  It should show what happens when you use the write return value as a call number.  It's small enough that it's probably not ENOSYS.